# Merge children of elements if they have same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a list that is nested, each level has some text and a list nested inside of it. I have to check on each level if the text is the same - if so, i want to merge elements together, so text wont repeat.

my HTML:

```
<ul class="ordered-cat">
    <li class="item-0 level-0-0">
        <span class="text">dom</span>
        <ul class="inner">
            <li class="item-1 level-1-1">
                <span class="text">kuh</span>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li class="item-2 level-2-2">
                        <span class="text">nap</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-0 level-1-0">
        <span class="text">dom</span>
        <ul class="inner">
            <li class="item-2 level-2-1">
                <span class="text">kuh</span>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li class="item-3 level-3-2">
                        <span class="text">pri</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-0 level-2-0">
        <span class="text">dom</span>
        <ul class="inner">
            <li class="item-3 level-3-1">
                <span class="text">kuh</span>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li class="item-4 level-4-2">
                        <span class="text">pripi</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

expected result:

```
<ul class="ordered-cat">
    <li class="item-0 level-0-0">
        <span class="text">dom</span>
        <ul class="inner">
            <li class="item-1 level-1-1">
                <span class="text">kuh</span>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li class="item-2 level-2-2">
                        <span class="text">nap</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-3 level-3-2">
                        <span class="text">pri</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-4 level-4-2">
                        <span class="text">pripi</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my jquery attempt:

```
function cleanMore() {
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var myarray = [];
        $('.item-' + i + '').each(function () {
            var beseda = $(this).children('.text').text();
            if (jQuery.inArray(beseda, myarray) !== -1) {
                myarray.push(beseda);
            }
        });
        for (j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++) {
            $('.item-' + i + '').each(function () {
                if () { }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted by going through each level separately and check their content, but i got stuck at the part where i had to check for duplicated and merge them together into 1 element.